# How to fetch the data from svn Repository using the label using svn commandline

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Manually through svn gui/commandline we can fetch the data from the svn based on Revision number,but my requirement is to fetch the data based on the label given in the log... please suggest me .. are there any tools for doing like this,Actually my requirement is to automate the whole manual process

Comment: There are not such concept as "label" in SVN. What is it - tag, branch, part of commit message?

Comment: It is part of commit message

Answer (score 0):

[`svn log --search`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search) and [`svn log --search-and`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search_and) for SVN 1.8+

Comment: svn log is a command it just displays the log ,but what i need is to filter based on the label given in the log message

Comment: @BalajiMurari - "filter" WHAT?! Use SVN-specific lingua or describe your business-task in business-terms: I'm not telepath, and I prefer not to waste my time on those who can not clearly express their thoughts

Comment: In svn for each check-in we have a log message right,in that message we have to mention label also,my requirement is based on the Label which has given in the log message ,have to fetch the files or checkin's